# Last Transaction Date

Tags: sql, db2

I have a file in DB2 with account numbers with a field for Last Transaction Date in YYYYMMDD format. If the Last Transaction Date is less than 6 months from today's date, those accounts will be categorised as Dormant Accounts. Is there are way to extract accounts where the Last Transaction Date is less than 6 months from today's date?

Last Transaction Date is a not a constant date for the accounts.

If the Last Transaction Date was in Time Stamp format, I'm sure it'll be easy.

Comment: Don't be to sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the expression

```
select * from yourtable
where TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(YOURLASTTRANSACTIONCOLUMN,'YYYYMMDD') > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 6 MONTHS
```

to select the desired records.

Comment: @Esperento57 - Why do you think I was suggesting not to use a cast?

Comment: @Esperento57 -- it is strange because I remember writing something last friday but I didn't delete it.  I don't know who did.